# JBDCTemplate Pass w/ multiple parameters

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Here is the thing... I can't pass the following statement with the following code "this" is never printed therefore the result set is 0 but the query seems right.

Query:

> select * from opportunities where title = 1 and (zipcode = 11738 or zipcode = 11720 or zipcode = 11727 or zipcode = 11741 or zipcode = 11742 or zipcode = 11755 or zipcode = 11763 or zipcode = 11776 or zipcode = 11779 or zipcode = 11784 or zipcode = 11953)
>
> ---

The Query above does return results.***

Code(just switched the title and zipcode positions still will return 0 results when you run code)

```
public Opportunity[] getOpportunitiesBy(String title, String zipcode, double miles) {
    title = ""+Constants.TITLES_MAP.get(title.toLowerCase());
    String[] nearbyZipcodes = getZipcodesWithinRadius(zipcode, miles);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("(zipcode = "+zipcode+" or zipcode = "); 
    for(String otherZips : nearbyZipcodes) {
        builder.append(otherZips+" or zipcode = ");
    }
    String formattedZips = Utilities.replaceLast(builder.toString(), " or zipcode = ", ")");
    System.out.println(title+","+formattedZips);
    List<Opportunity> opportunities = this.jdbcTemplate.query("select * from opportunities where ? and title = ?",
            new Object[] { formattedZips, title}, new RowMapper<Opportunity>() {
                public Opportunity mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    Opportunity temp = new Opportunity();
                    System.out.println("this");
                    String[] candidateIds = rs.getString("candidateIds").split(",");
                    temp.setCandidateIds(Utilities.StringToIntArray(candidateIds));
                    temp.setCompany(rs.getString("company"));
                    temp.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
                    temp.setHtml(rs.getString("post_data"));
                    temp.setZipcode(rs.getString("zipcode"));
                    temp.setTitle(rs.getInt("title"));
                    try {
                        temp.setLogoImg(new URI(rs.getString("logo_img")));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return temp;
                }
            });
    return opportunities.toArray(new Opportunity[opportunities.size()]);
}
```

The output from the initial println(title+","+formattedZips)

> 1,(zipcode = 11738 or zipcode = 11720 or zipcode = 11727 or zipcode = 11741 or zipcode = 11742 or zipcode = 11755 or zipcode = 11763 or zipcode = 11776 or zipcode = 11779 or zipcode = 11784 or zipcode = 11953)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your setup.

First you shouldn't be using concatenation to create a (partial) query, second that isn't the way parameterized queries work. The parameters are escaped before putting them in, so I doubt the query is what you expect it to be.

SQL has the `in` clause instead of doing a `zipcode or zipcode or zipcode`) use a single `in` clause in your query. However their you have a problem again as you want to pass in an array. To fix that use a [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) instead of a plain `JdbcTemplate`. Then rewrite your query to use named parameters and an `in` clause.

```
public Opportunity[] getOpportunitiesBy(String title, String zipcode, double miles) {
   String sql = "select * from opportunities where title = :title and zipcode in (:zips)";
   title = ""+Constants.TITLES_MAP.get(title.toLowerCase());
   String[] nearbyZipcodes = getZipcodesWithinRadius(zipcode, miles);

   Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
   params.put("title", nearbyZipcodes);
   params.put("zips", near)

   return this.jdbcTemplate.query(sql, params, new RowMapper<Opportunity>() {
       public Opportunity mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
           Opportunity temp = new Opportunity();
           System.out.println("this");
           String[] candidateIds = rs.getString("candidateIds").split(",");
           temp.setCandidateIds(Utilities.StringToIntArray(candidateIds));
           temp.setCompany(rs.getString("company"));
           temp.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
           temp.setHtml(rs.getString("post_data"));
           temp.setZipcode(rs.getString("zipcode"));
           temp.setTitle(rs.getInt("title"));
           try {
               temp.setLogoImg(new URI(rs.getString("logo_img")));
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }
           return temp;
       });

}
```

Something like that should do the trick, however it might be easier if your `getZipCodesWithinRadius` is also using a query you might even use that as a sub select in your in clause and simply pass in the given `zipcode` and `miles`, that way you would have a single query getting the results in one go (instead of 2 queries and all the jdbc stuff going along with that).